# How do I get jquery variable value to be read by PHP $_POST?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm able to successfully get all the values from a multi-select form into one nice delimited variable, but I can't figure out how to get the value to my PHP script?  How do I get the 'output' value read by PHP's $_POST array? Any help would. Be. Awesome. :D

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ValidatePageForm() {
    var result = new Array();

    $("#select-to option").each(function() {
        result.push($(this).val());
    });

    var output = result.join("-");  
    alert(output);


}
</script>
```

Comment: do you understand client-side vs server-side ?

Comment: Which value do you want go get where? I'm confused. Do you want get the value of $_POST "inserted" into jQuery or do you want to get the values from jQuery-function "inserted" into PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose you have a form

```
<form>
<input type="hidden" name="output" id="output">
....
</form>
```

send javascript variable to HTML

```
var output = result.join("-");  
$('#output').val(output);
```

and when you submit the form 
you wil get data in **$_POST['output']**

Comment: You're amazing.  So simple. It works :). You saved me. Seriously this front-end stuff throws me for a loop.  BUT give me crazy back-end work and I'll knock your socks off!

Answer (score 0):

I believe your looking for something like echo $_POST['value']; ??

Comment: And yes I know about $_POST vars...but for some reason using this fancy jquery on the front-end with my multiselect - the variables are not being posted with the multiselect (it allows you to shift elements back and forth from one multiselect to another, then up/down to reorder - not your typical multiple select in plain HTML for my PHP to read...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery serialize to post all the data of the form including multi select

```
var submit_data = $('#output').serialize();
var post_data = submit_data ;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'submitform.php',
    data: post_data,
    success: function(data)
    {
    }
});
```

You will get all the value in $_POST on submitform.php

Let me know it works for you